# How to find scout?

Tags: star-conflict

I have "Destroy the cyber scout" mission, few times I've left station and saw fighting scout... though was not able to kill him: either he killed my, or other guys killed the scout...

Upon that I was flying around the station and could not find any scout anymore...

How can I meet scout?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heh, I still don't know how to find it for sure, but looks like if you fly no too far from stations, (8-10 km) you will find some flying objects (old broken stations) and those scouts are spawned here.

May be try to find were are active fights and check those places...

Answer (score 0):

I found the cyber scout to the south east of the Jericoh base on the same map - in a tube/ribcage like structure. Took me a long while too, stupid family guard keep getting the kills as it spawns lol.